# Find Save/Cancel button at FormCreated Event in Jquery- JTable and append another Button to this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

At Jquery- JTable we have some actions and fields with fix button (cancel,save,delete) buttons , I want to Add other buttons(with post back functions) when Form Created exactly near by default buttons but i can not find it  and i dont know how to add my button to jtable.